# KineticJS and HTML

Tags: html, kineticjs

I have a situation, the images moving left to right and viceversa, after a certain bound area the images have to hide(invisible) from the stage and when they return back it should be visible.   My tween is like this :

```
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: puzzle, 
            duration: 22,
            x: puzzle.getX()+700,       
            easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
            onFinish : function(){
                  this.reverse();
            }
});
```

anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use clipping regions**

You can put your puzzle object on a group and set a clipping region on that group.

When your puzzle moves out of the group's clipping region it will not be displayed.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hzTM7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var group=new Kinetic.Group({
        clip:{x:50,y:50,width:100,height:100},
    });
    layer.add(group);

    var bk=new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:50,
        y:50,
        width:100,
        height:100,
        fill:"blue",
        opacity:0.10,
    });
    group.add(bk);


    var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:70,
        y:70,
        radius: 15,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
    });
    group.add(circle1);
    layer.draw();

    var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: circle1, 
                duration: 2,
                x: circle1.getX()+120,       
                easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
                onFinish : function(){
                      this.reverse();
                }
    });

    $("#myButton").click(function(){ tween.play(); });

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="myButton">Tween</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```